# How to implement updating article system.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop, text

I am working on a news website, whereby anyone can edit a post, extend the contents or correct typos and everything.. now, the problem is to protect the articles from vandalism or any unwanted articles, I want to keep the original article, so I can review the update with the original one before merging them, so this means, that I may need two rows, 1 for the original post, which will not be changed, the second will contain the original post, but anyone can edit into it. So, I can compare the two rows ... and then there is another problem that, what if an articles was edited by more than one person? anyway... I am trying to stick with making two entries for article, one to be edited one with the original or only articles approved by me...

but, the real problem is how to compare the differences between two articles?

do I make some sort of a loop, just iterating through both contents checking if each character is similar to the the original one? that sounds like a lot of task. the [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function only fives a percentage of numerical value, so that function is only good it the editable replica of the article is not same as the original article...

I am sure this could be effectively done with javascript, but I am not sure how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you didnt specify on what restrictions you want to do this, for comaparing my best option would be using linux `cat`

Comment: @ManZzup Thanks, but what more could've possibly given that what I already stated above? I just need to compare two block of texts to weed out the difference of characters.

Comment: for an example are you able to run linux commands from your php script? if so using `cat` would be feasible

Answer (score 1):

This is almost binary difference
The service provided by programs like svn and git
And it is very difficult to recreate
I suggest you create a temporary table to store all modified versions of that post, and then you choose the correct one as admin, in the final the temporary table is deleted

Comment: Thanks, but I was hopping for PHP solution.